# History of the run command box in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-history

Most Linux desktops have a dialog box that opens at the press of `alt+F2` where you can run simple commands like `suspend` and `shutdown`. Where is the history of commands of this dialog box stored?

I know for a fact that this history is separate from the terminal's history, which is stored in `~/bash_history`.

Also, is this thing known by any special name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on *which* desktop you're asking about.

GNOME 3 (including recent Ubuntu versions) stores the history in GSettings at `org.gnome.shell`:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell command-history

dconf-editor org.gnome.shell command-history

dconf read /org/gnome/shell/command-history
```

[Very old Unity versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122473/delete-alt-f2-history) stored it in dconf at `/desktop/unity/runner/history`. Use dconf-editor to access it (the corresponding GSettings location is likely a bit complex).

Xfce4 stores it in a file at `~/.cache/xfce4/xfce4-appfinder/history`.

Old GNOME 2 used to store the history in GConf (*not* the same thing as GSettings/dconf), at location `/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/history-gnome-run`. The tools are gconftool-2 and gconf-editor.

Comment: About the desktop, I'm interested in knowing about Cinnamon DE.

Comment: I would expect it to be nearly the same as GNOME Shell except at `org.cinnamon.something`.